# Sendgrid has no attribute 'Mail'

Tags: python, email, heroku

I'm attempting to launch a Flask Heroku app that sends emails when people log onto a page.

I'm trying to use SendMail as Flask-Mail doesn't work (it will send a few emails then just....stop, there is nothing in the error log). I'm trying to follow the instruction on the site

```
from sendgrid import *
sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient('xxxx@heroku.com', 'xxxx', raise_errors = True)

message = sendgrid.Mail(to='xxxx@xxxx.com', subject='Example', html='Body', text='Body', from_email='xxxx@xxxx.com')
status, msg = sg.send(message)
sg.send(message)
```

But I get this error thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mailtest.py", line 7, in <module>
    message = sendgrid.Mail(to='xxxx@xxxx.com', subject='Example', html='
Body', text='Body', from_email='xxxx@xxxx.com')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Mail'
```

The app is up-to-date, I'm not sure why sendgrid doesn't have the mail attribute. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, try this:

```
import sendgrid
from sendgrid import SendGridError, SendGridClientError, SendGridServerError
sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient('xxx@heroku.com', 'xxx')

message = sendgrid.Mail()
message.add_to('Mister Mail <xxx@xxx.com>')
message.set_from('Mrs Mail <xxx@xxxxx.com>')
message.set_subject('Example')
message.set_html('HTML Body')
message.set_text('Text Body')
msg = sg.send(message)

return msg
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the sendgrid module like this:

```
import sendgrid
```

Comment: It's no longer throwing the error but the message still isn't being sent/received. I can't see anything in the logs that show why that is.